# Why isn't the nurturing of musical talent and the writing of poetry in praise of Hashem a formal part of Jewish education?

Tags: music

Tehillim 150 talks about Procaliming His praise with the call of Shofar, with the psalter and harp, with the timbrel and dance, with stringed instruments and the flute, with the loud sounding cymbals and stirring cymbals (The Hirsch Siddur, Feldheim 1972).

This Tehillim seems to talking about a full fledged orchestra.

There are also many exhortations in Tehillim to sing and use language to Hashem in praise of His wonders etc.

Why doesn't Jewish education put more of an emphasis on nurturing us to express our relationship with Hashem through our own personal music, song and poetry, each according to his talent.

Thus, whether one is happy or sad a Jew would express their emotions through either music, song or poetry. Not just listening to someone else's music but expressing their own emotions through these mediums.

Comment: There is a Biblical Mitzva to have music in the Temple. I don't know what could be more emphasized than that. That's super high level importance.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think the intent of the question is specifically contemporary Judaism. user9874, is that right? If so, please [edit] to make that clearer. Also, could you focus the post more to be a single, answerable question? The last two paragraphs appear to be recommendations, rather than aspects of a question. I think focusing down specifically to something like "Why don't we emulate the instrumental music aspect of the Tempple in our shul service?" could work well.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Contemporary Judaism also has a Biblical Mitzva to have music in the Temple. I don't know what could be more emphasized than that. That's super high level importance.

Comment: @DoubleAA Contemporary Jewish practice, then. Yes, the Temple service remains 100% part of our religion, but it is (due to the multitude of our sins) not part of our contemporary practice.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Contemporary Jewish practice is actively working towards having that music. It's a very high priority in fact. I don't know what could be more emphasized than that. That's super high level importance.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question is why there isn't music, not why there isn't working towards getting to have music.

Comment: @IsaacMoses but (and excuse me if I am getting this line of argument wrong) doesn't that argument equate to "why isn't there sacrifice today, and not just why isn't there work towards sacrifice"? The music in question is bound to the B"HMDSH. Maybe the underlying question should be clarified to discuss music as separate from temple service.

Comment: @Danno, One could ask the same question about sacrifices, and the answer may or may not be the same. The question, asked with sufficient detail, may or may not be the same, either. That is, as explained above, I think that this question should be sharpened a bit, at least. In addition, it could probably be strengthened further, if the asker is so-inclined, by discussing the idea of emulation of the Temple in general and asking why instrumental music isn't part of that, but I don't think that's essential to making this a viable question post.

Comment: @Danno (and others...u just happen to be the latest comment :-) I think OP may be asking why the reciting o fTehillim (during davening) isn't accompanied by music / instrumentation. I wouldn't mind that, but between you and me, Salmon Rossi composed terrific vocal-only music for the majority of Tehillim. It would be nice if people sang them, but during the weekday, it's prob. *tircha detzibbur*. Besides, it seems that people get better music from their smart phones, these days ;-)

Comment: @IsaacMoses "discussing the idea of emulation of the Temple in general " is, IMHO the heart of the question and has to be addressed before any conclusions can be drawn or discussed. Is that exactly what we do? Is that a goal or a driving factor? If that is not what the question hinges on, wee need to know.

Comment: @Danno, How much knowledge  to inject into the question is up to the asker. "They had instruments in the Temple. Shuls are like the Temple in some ways. <Any demonstration thereof>. Why don't we use instruments in shuls?" is a sufficient question, AFAIC. Sure, a more sophisticated question could be asked, and could be more valuable, but if the original point of curiosity is not at that level of sophistication, that doesn't make it unaddressable. That said, in accordance with what I said in my first comment, I voted to close this question in its present state.

Comment: @IsaacMoses the simple formulation would be great, but, unless I'm missing something, the question as asked lacks the "Shuls are like the Temple in some ways" connection so I don't know if that is what is driving it.

Comment: @Danno, I agree. You're welcome to join me in voting to close as Unclear, if you haven't already.

Comment: The Temple service was accompanied by musical instruments, played by the Leviim. They even played them (and even could tune/repair them) on Shabbat. 

The lack of a Temple is "mournful" so we do not use them to serve Hashem now. (e.g. psalm 137 and it is said they cut off the ends of their fingers so they couldn't play their instruments).

At one point it was suggested that all musical instruments should be "stopped" to mourn for the temple but it was restricted to just the period before Tisha B'av (The Omer restriction came later).

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't Judaism put more of an emphasis on expressing our love for Hashem through music, song and poetry in a formal sense as in the Shul on days when musical instruments can be played. Or just with formal musical concerts and the like.

It does.  Music has always been a huge part of the Jewish liturgical experience, across all cultures of Judaism around the world.  Throughout the centuries, great poets have been composing piyutim and pizmonim -- and they continue still today -- in Hebrew, Aramaic, and their own vernaculars.  Traditionally Jews have not been literate in music, for the most part, with the role of the cantor learned by talent and rote rather than theoretical learning and music theory.  This is no longer true today, thankfully, but it might be one reason why most of the literally thousands of piyutim in our liturgical repertoire don't usually come with tunes attached.

That said, many tunes have been passed down traditionally for centuries -- not really *that* many centuries, but in the Ashkenazic tradition these melodies are called Misinai, from Sinai.  They include many of the iconic pieces of High Holiday liturgy, like the great Aleinu and Kol Nidrei.  Using the proper melodies for the liturgy in general is actually something halachah is actively concerned with.  It is considered imperative to chant the liturgy or use tunes in the appropriate mode -- which does vary across cultures, but you should stick to the ones used by your own culture.  For example, in Shabbat Shacharit, the proper nusach is to change modes from the Nishmat mode to the Ahavah Rabbah mode at "shevach" in El Adon.  Do people do this?  No, not really, but it *is* the supposed proper nusach.

Plenty of people put on concerts of Jewish music, including instrumental works and chazanut as well as folk songs and bakashot and z'mirot and you name it.  And, of course, modern Jewish institutions train chazanim to use the correct melodies for all of the liturgy.  We may not be allowed to use instruments halachically, but, first, PLENTY of people do so anyway, especially in the Reform communities of the world, and second, we still have our voices!

Also, while the center-right Orthodox establishment may not emphasize music as much as other groups and denominations, the Chasidim are *way* into music.  The Baal Shem Tov taught that the niggun could elevate the soul spiritually, and his followers, even today, continue to use niggunim in this way.  These niggunim are often written by Rebbes themselves, and it's important that they be sung precisely and with several customs -- for example, usually each strain of the niggun should be sung twice.  (There is a reason, like always, but I don't remember what it is.)  Each Chasidic group has its own melodies, some of which also become popular throughout Judaism.

Finally, Jews have an immensely rich musical tradition that varies across the world, across denominations, and across the liturgy and Tanach.  Why is music education not stressed in traditional yeshivot?  I don't know.  I didn't go to them.  Maybe it actually *is* stressed and I just wasn't told -- I know of several schools with strong cantorial programs.  But even if they're mumbling, Jews are always singing.  Z'mirot, nigunim, pizmonim, t'hilim, you name it, we're always singing.  Maybe instrumental music we don't do as much since the Temple is no longer standing, but we haven't stopped singing since.

Comment: Where did you learn of a nusach change in El Adon?

Comment: There's a YUTorah talk by Cantor Sherwin Goffin -- I don't remember which one, I'm sorry -- where he mentions this.  In his Be A Ba'al Tefillah collection, he actually switches as Tif'eret in the middle of the Shevach paragraph.  [Haskel Lookstein](http://www.ramaz.org/nusach/index.html) just mentions switching after El Adon, but he assumes El Adon is sung rather than chanted.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my original question. Your answer is very interesting and informative and has helped me clarify what I really wanted to ask.